# Have to decrement one value which is stored using shared preference according to the current date

Tags: android

I have two dates in string format and stored it using shared preference. The first date (current date) is set to date picker date and second one is the date after adding 41 days to the first date. In a button I have to get the difference between the two dates in days and it is stored using shared preference. The problem is, that I have to decrement the difference between these two dates according to each current date. How can do that? Please help.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.end;
//import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.enddate;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.imageView;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.myImageViewText;
//import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.startdate;
import static com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.R.id.textView3;

/**
 * Created by aiswarya on 3/24/2017.
 */

public class Fasting extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton backb;
    ImageButton reset;
    TextView startdate,enddate;
    ImageView remaining;
    TextView remainingtext;
    SharedPreferences myprefs;
    public String dayys;
    public  long from,to;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitydate);
        backb=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.back);
        reset= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
        // startdate= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        // enddate= (TextView) findViewById(textView3);
        remaining=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
        //remainingtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);





        backb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Fasting.this,
                        Home.class);
                startActivity(intent);


            }

        });

        reset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startdate.setText("START DATE");
                enddate.setText("END DATE");
                remainingtext.setText("REMAINING DAYS");


            }
        });

        myprefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);

        init();


    }



    public void selectFrom(View v) {
        final Calendar today = Calendar.getInstance();

        DatePickerDialog dp = new DatePickerDialog(Fasting.this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {


                Log.d("date", dayOfMonth + "/" + month + "/" + year);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
                cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2)).setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 41);

                ((TextView)findViewById(textView3)).setText(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));



                long from = today.getTimeInMillis();
                long to = cal.getTimeInMillis();
                int days = (int) TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toDays(Math.abs(from - to));
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "DAYS = " + days, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                final String dayss=String.valueOf(days);

                remaining.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v){
                        remainingtext.setText(""+dayss+" DAYS");

                    }
                });

            }
        }, today.get(Calendar.YEAR), today.get(Calendar.MONTH), today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        dp.show();
    }

    private  void init(){
        startdate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        enddate=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        remainingtext=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.myImageViewText);


        readPreferences();
    }

    public void onSave(View view) {
        String start=startdate.getText().toString();
        String end=enddate.getText().toString();
        String rem=remainingtext.getText().toString();
        //int ageText=Integer.parseInt(age.getText().toString());

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myprefs.edit();
        editor.putString("keyname",start);
        editor.putString("keyage",end);
        editor.putString("keyrem",rem);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public void onReset(View view) {

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=myprefs.edit();
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        readPreferences();

    }

    public void readPreferences(){
        String stl= myprefs.getString("keyname","");
        startdate.setText(stl);
        //int vall=myprefs.getInt("keyage",0);
        String vall=myprefs.getString("keyage","");
        enddate.setText(String.valueOf(vall));
        String remdays=myprefs.getString("keyrem","");
        remainingtext.setText(String.valueOf(remdays));





    }



}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:orientation="vertical"

    tools:context="com.example.aiswarya.mantraapp.Fasting">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/linir_back"
        >
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/back"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/linir_back"
            android:src="@drawable/back_button"/>

        <TextView
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="FASTING"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlue"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            />


    </LinearLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:visibility="visible"

        android:onClick="selectFrom"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"

        android:text="START DATE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"

        android:visibility="visible"
        android:text="END DATE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />


    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/submit4resized1"
        android:onClick="onSave"
        android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
        />


    <ImageButton

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"


        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:src="@drawable/resetbutton"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"
        android:onClick="onReset" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="216dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:onClick="showDiff"
            android:src="@drawable/new1"
            android:layout_marginRight="63dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="63dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myImageViewText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="REMAINING DAYS"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:layout_marginRight="41dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="41dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/myImageView"
            android:layout_marginBottom="65dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: you can decrease it directly from variable you have store like a=b+c then p=a-1

Comment: Sorry,i have to do it  with a condition which checks current date.Means, if the remaining days value is 41 today, it have to be 40 by tomorrow.

Comment: yes you can again check difference of your `a`  value and current date if is 41 then assign p= 41-1

Comment: you have two date current and currentdate+41 you are trying difference with today's date?

Comment: Yes.i wants to decrement remaining days value according to todays'date.

Comment: what is remaining days?

Comment: Its the difference between current date which i stored using shared preference  and the end date.

Comment: Its the difference between current date which i stored using shared preference  and the end date. i have to decrease remaining days value for each day

Comment: end date is currentdate+41?

Comment: so you want to decrease the difference if you change the start date to lower than your current date?

Answer (score 0):

[image: check this]

your apps showing diffrence in messagebox after changing the date from todays date to later 24 , 23 , 22 ,....

Comment: so you make 22-04-2017 so it will be 36?

Comment: I have to decrease remaining days value one by one for each day automatically. That is when i open my app next day the start date, end date and remaining days will be there because those were stored using shared preference.But i wants when I open my app next day remaining days must have to automatically decrease by one. I cant change the start date for getting the new remaining days. Please refer my java code and help me.

Comment: if you change your start days your end date also be change because of  41 you add it so do you want to change it base on start date or make it same also nextday or tomorrow? because of that your value is increase 41+new start date.

Comment: Yes. want to change it base on start date and make it same also next day,  tomorrow. But I cant insert new start date.I have to display old start date without any change

Comment: I have to display old start date without any change.Only have to change remaining days

Comment: so you have to display start date and end date always same just change value in remaining days everyday only?

Comment: Yes That is what i exactly wants to do. Could you please help me

Comment: Ok. Thank you in advance

Comment: you have to set your date first time  onload of activity or button click?

Comment: start date is set for first time when clicking on the textview

Comment: nexttime start and end set to automatically ?

Comment: start and end date always have to remain constants until we press reset.only remaining days have to be change

Comment: when we enter start date for first time it is stored using shared preference.so it will be remaining there and i doesn't wants to change it.Only have to decrease remaining days in everyday